Emit model updating from keydown event in vue
I have keydown handler for fast uppercasing/lowercasing with Shift + Up/Down key:
export function onCaseChange(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (event.shiftKey && (event.key === 'ArrowDown' || event.key === 'ArrowUp')) {
        const textfield = event.target as HTMLInputElement

        event.preventDefault()

        const processText = (str: string) => {
            if (event.key === 'ArrowDown')
                return str.toLowerCase()
            else
                return str.toUpperCase()
        }

        const selectionStart = textfield.selectionStart
        const selectionEnd = textfield.selectionEnd

        if (!selectionStart || !selectionEnd)
            return

        if (textfield.selectionStart == textfield.selectionEnd) {
            textfield.value = processText(textfield.value)
        } else {
            const left = textfield.value.substring(0, selectionStart)
            const middle = textfield.value.substring(selectionStart, selectionEnd)
            const right = textfield.value.substring(selectionEnd)

            textfield.value = left + processText(middle) + right
        }

        textfield.selectionStart = selectionStart
        textfield.selectionEnd = selectionEnd
    }
}

Without Vue I could do this before. But with Vue framework it doesn't works. When I press Shift + Up the value changes and immediately changes to previous state. That's because my input have binding to model, in my example it is a ref value:
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { onCaseChange } from './caseChanger'

const trademarkVerbal = ref("")
const otherValue1 = ref("")
const otherValue2 = ref("")
...
</script>

<template>
<v-text-field v-model="trademarkVerbal" @keydown="onCaseChange" label="Trademark verbal"/>
<v-text-field v-model="otherValue1" @keydown="onCaseChange" label="Other value 1"/>
<v-text-field v-model="otherValue2" @keydown="onCaseChange" label="Other value 2"/>
...
</template>

How to force model change in my onCaseChange method? I want to use this method on many inputs, so I need somehow to pass model name to event handler or something that

In fact, adding textfield.dispatchEvent(new Event('input')) to end of onCaseChange method solve my problem. Thanks @Estus Flask for the tip

Notice that it may require setTimeout or other minimal delay to always keep a model in sync, as shown in the answer

Thanks, but it works without any timeout

v-model is syntax sugar for a specific event handler that relies on the provided model as a single source of truth, it may be possible to affect how it processes model values with custom modifiers, but not how it processes DOM events. It needs to be desugared, a composable could be used in order to make it reusable:
const useKeyCase = (model = ref()) => {
  const keyHandler = (e) => {
    ...
    model.value = ...
  },

  return [model, keyHandler];
}

const [trademarkVerbal, trademarkVerbalKeyHandler] = useKeyCase()

...

<input :value="trademarkVerbal" @keydown="trademarkVerbalKeyHandler"/>

Directives are good for reusable DOM-related code, but they would need to re-emit input/change event to make v-model handle the updates:
const vKeyCase = {
  beforeMount(el) {
    el.addEventListener('keydown', el.dataset.keyCaseHandler = e => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        ...
        el.value = ...;
        el.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
      })
    });
  }, 
  unmounted(el) {
    el.removeEventListener('keydown', el.dataset.keyCaseHandler);
  }
};

...

<input v-model="trademarkVerbal" v-key-case />

This will result in a model containing unprocessed value at some points.
